# Modelmetadata is populated for outer model, but not inner model,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata

I need reading material on how modelmetadata is populated and when the OnMetadataCreated method is called in the framework. When I created a viewmodel that contains a nested viewmodel, OnMetadataCreated was not called for the properties of the inner viewmodel, but it was created for the properties in the outermodel.

My current solution circumvents this by using reflection in the view to access the properites and attributes of the inner view model. (Normally I would access these attributes and do things with them in the OnMetadataCreated.)

Comment: it's hard to understand what you mean, could you add some code?

Comment: okay, edited to help clarify meaning